# Equivalent of Octave's `meshgrid` in Chapel

Tags: simulation, hpc, chapel

Octave provides a utility function called [`meshgrid`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/meshgrid.html) that generates point fields.  This is very useful in large scale simulations for evaluating functions at certain points.  With Chapels `Domain` feature, the mesh could be distributed.  Is there a library that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't fully general (or tested in detail), but how about this for a prototype

```
proc meshgrid(arrs : ?T ... ?nsize) where
  isArray(T) && (nsize > 0)
{
  const lo = arrs.indices.first;
  // All elements have the same type T, so we only need to check that.
  assert(arrs[lo].rank==1);

  type retType = nsize*arrs[lo].eltType;

  // Define the output domain
  var tmp : nsize*range;
  for ii in arrs.indices do (tmp(ii),) = arrs[ii].domain.dims();
  var Dom = {(...tmp)};

  var retval : [Dom] retType;
  forall ijk in Dom {
    for ii in lo.. #nsize do retval[ijk](ii) = arrs(ii)[ijk(ii)];
  }

  return retval;
}
```

Here's an example

```
var x = [1,2,5];
var y = [2,1];

writeln(meshgrid(x,y));
```

which yields

```
(1, 2) (1, 1)
(2, 2) (2, 1)
(5, 2) (5, 1)
```

I chose to save the indices as tuple elements, since that seemed most natural in terms of the ways I might use this (given Chapel promotion).